# Google DFP Interstitial and Banner Ads will work in same Ad UNIT ID in iOS?

Tags: ios, banner, google-dfp, interstitial

I have created on Google DFP Ad unit id for IOS App , it's working great for DFP Banner views but am using same uint id for Interstitial Ad view. it doesn't show any ad in that view.

I want to know, can we use same id for both Interstitial and Banner Ad View?

Comment: sorry, what is DFP, is there ability to set log_level and check that for appropriate info?

Answer (score 1):

Interstitial ad requests are bucketed into 320x480, 480x320, 768x1024, or 1024x768 sizes. Most likely you're looking for 320x480 if your app is in portrait, or 480x320 if your app is in landscape. To get interstitial inventory, you'll need to make your DFP line item target the right size and also have a creative set up on that line item.